How do I compare two attributes in Journey Builder Decision Split?
I have an email with an interactive form which asks users to specify how many properties they have in total.
I already know how many properties they have listed on our platform.
So, when the user submits the form, I need a decision split in my journey that segments users if total properties is greater than number of current listings.
If true, then send users Email A and create a Task in SF.
If false, then send users Email B and end journey.
This is how I have configured my decision split. I have tested it, but using the attribute comparison like this doesn't seem to work. In every test case, the contact went down the default pathway. Both attributes are numbers.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Ideally, I don't want to have to create a SQL and automation to run the calculation between fields, as this would be an inefficient use of my very limited Automations quota.
